# java,javac commands work perfectly but still getting error java_home path does not exist

Tags: path, environment-variables, javac, wildfly-10, java-home

i am trying to run standalone.bat file from (wildfly-10.1.0.Final) folder
but i am getting error in command prompt

[image]
java, javac commands are working perfectly fine

[image]

Environment variables are set like this:

```
JAVA_HOME   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin
```

please help me 
Thanks

Comment: JAVA_HOME should point to a single bin folder in your case it is multiple paths concattenated.

Comment: point to single bin folder of jdk or jre



?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set JAVA_HOME to a **single** directory - it is not like a PATH environment variable.  I believe that it will be the second part of the path you currently have set.  Realistically you likely don't even need to set this environment variable.  If `java` and `javac` are already on your path you won't need it.

Comment: thank you so much. When i removed only one of the two i was still getting the same error but when  i removed both jdk,jre paths from JAVA_HOME,it worked for me.